# Setting Text Columns to a Text in a Specific Paragraph Only in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to add text to a template file, but I want this text to be in 3 columns (if it reaches end of page, it goes up and sets a new column near it, like [this](http://creativepro.com/indesign-how-to-balance-columns-with-vertical-justification/)).

I'm entering the text this way:

```
var pText = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
pText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
pText.Range.Text = strAll;
pText.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

And I want only it to be formatted into 3 text columns.

I tried `pText.Range.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(3);`, but it formats for the entire page and I don't want that. I tried looking up how to select this specific paragraph as it is not yet added but couldn't find any result.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
docWord.Sections[docWord.Content.Sections.Count].PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(3);
```